# Open excel file in new window (i.e. not an existing Excel instance)

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to ensure that an excel file passed to my application is opened in it's own window rather than an existing Excel instance.  Is there a way of telling the Process to do this?  The following code always uses an existing instance if present.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = myExcelFile;
process.Start();
```

thanks

Matt

Answer (score 10):

Try the following.

```
Process process = new Process();
Process.Start("Excel.exe", myExcelFile);
```

Other option is, if you use Interop (i.e. `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` ), you can do it as follows. This will always open the file in a new instance.

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
string workbookPath = (@"C:\Sample.xlsx");
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
    0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
    true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```